# how to edit datagridview while program is running

Tags: c#

Please, I've been researching on this for long now and every solution I tried still doesn't work. I just need a small code snippet I can copy and paste and find out where I've been going wrong. Or even find out whether the datagridview of my system is not working well. thanks

Comment: post what you have, probably need an update panel if you want to modify it once its already working (for a web app). Or even use javascript (also for a web app).

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = false;
            dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;

        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I've solved the problem. the mistake was that I was loading the database with sqlDataReader which loads the database in read only mode. So I used sqlDataAdapter and dataset which loads the database in edit mode. This is the correct code below

```
           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;



        try
        {
            String myConnection = "data source = KEGA\\SQLEXPRESS; database = KEGA; integrated security=SSPI";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnection);

            con.Open();
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select Eid as 'Employee Id', name as 'First Name', surname as 'Last Name', age as 'Age', gender as 'Gender', phone_number as 'Phone Number', bank as 'Bank', acct_name as 'Account Name', acct_number as 'Account Number' from Clients", con);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Clients");
            Clients_view.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`